# "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `fk_idbrand` on serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm currently building a django app and I'm serializing my views, but when applying the serializer to the model is experiencing an error that I've been unable to fix:

models.py

```
class vehicles_brand(models.Model):
    pk_idbrand= models.AutoField(db_column='PK_IdBrand', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fk_idcountry= models.ForeignKey(locations_country, on_delete= models.CASCADE, db_column='FK_IdLocationCountry', related_name='Country')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vehicles_brand'
        verbose_name_plural = "Vehicle Brands"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class vehicles_model(models.Model):
    pk_idmodel = models.AutoField(db_column='PK_IdModel', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None)
    fk_idbrand= models.ForeignKey(vehicles_brand, on_delete= models.CASCADE, db_column='FK_IdVehicleBrand', related_name='Brand')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vehicles_model'
        verbose_name_plural = "Vehicle Models"
```

serializers.py

```
class brandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = vehicles_brand
        fields = '__all__'

class modelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    brand = brandSerializer(source="FK_IdVehicleBrand", many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = vehicles_model
        fields = '__all__'
```

output:

```
"Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `fk_idbrand` on serializer `modelSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'fk_idbrand'."
```

I've checked my models and the serializers but for me everything seems to be ok, thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class modelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # actually It should be Brand which is related name in table 
    Brand = brandSerializer(source="FK_IdVehicleBrand",many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
         model = vehicles_model
         fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the same message is shown.